# Убрать надпись при вводе логина

Tags: html

Добрый день. При вводе логина на сайте пользователям необходимо стирать надпись "Логин". Вот код

```
input class="bar" id="user" name="login_name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Username') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='';" value="Логин" type="text"
```

Не подскажете, что с ним сделать, чтобы при нажатии на окно ввода логина надпись убиралась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени `value="Логин"` на `placeholder="Логин"`